# SoapObject Result returns anyType{} as value

Tags: web-services, wsdl, android-ksoap2

```
package com.example.gramaniladharidetails;

import java.util.Vector;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.Marshal;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.MarshalFloat;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

  public class GramaNiladhari extends Activity {
private static String SOAP_ACTION1= "http://localhost/getGramaNiladhariData";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://119.235.4.217/";
private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "getGramaNiladhariData";
private static String URL = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grama_niladhari);


    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            final String gndLifeCode = prov;
            String LifeCode = "3-2-09-060";
            request.addProperty("gndLifeCode", LifeCode);
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);


            SupportThread st = new SupportThread();
            Log.i("Request", request.toString());
            st.execute(request);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_grama_niladhari, menu);
    return true;
}

private class SupportThread extends
        AsyncTask<SoapObject, Object, SoapObject> {

    @Override
    protected SoapObject doInBackground(SoapObject... req) {
        SoapObject result = null;
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(req[0]);
        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "SerializeInfo",
                new SerializeInfo().getClass());

        Marshal floatMarshal = new MarshalFloat();
        floatMarshal.register(envelope);

        envelope.dotNet = true;

        try {
            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();



            if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
                String str = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
                Log.i("*******", str);

            } else {
                int elementCount = result.getPropertyCount();

                if (elementCount > 0) {
                    String element;

                    for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {


                        element = result.getProperty(i).toString();
                        Log.d("This is an element", Integer.toString(i)
                                + " --" + element);


                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result != null) {
            String response_name = result.getName();

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            tv.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
        }

        else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } 
    }
}
```

}

The webservice method i am calling retuns a complexType Object called GramaNiladhari. It consists of 5 string types. 
When I run this code I get the following SoapObject result.

```
anyType{gnName=anyType{}; address=anyType{}; workingDays=anyType{}; gnDivision=anyType{}; contactNumber=anyType{}; }
```

But here i am missing the **values**,and they are replaced with **anyType{}** .
How can I retrieve the real values ?

**I've edit my question.**

This is the parsed request in XML.

```
    <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body>
<getGramaNiladhariData xmlns="http://119.235.4.217/GNService/">
<gndLifeCode i:type="d:string">1-1-21-065</gndLifeCode>
</getGramaNiladhariData></v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

And this is the result after calling the web service.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <soap:Body> <getGramaNiladhariDataResponse xmlns="http://localhost/"> <getGramaNiladhariDataResult><gnName /><address /><workingDays /><gnDivision /><contactNumber /></getGramaNiladhariDataResult></getGramaNiladhariDataResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Checking the request,it seems that the request has passed well(even the request parameter gndLifeCode with its correct value, 1-1-21-065 ).

But the response, is null.All the elements I need to retrieve have empty tags.

Can this be a problem in web service.
I've checked this web service in SoapUI & it works well there(even it works in SoapClient).
Yet can't figure out what the issue here is?

Comment: Weird you using getProperty() it should throw you an exception. Are you sure that you are using the latest version of SoapObject?

Comment: Yes,I used getProperty() method & it didn't throw any exception.                                                           I have ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar library in my lib directory. Isn't it the latest version.                                                             Should I change the VER11 to VER12 in the line, SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

Comment: My SOAP_ACTION and NAMESAPACE are as below.                   `private static String SOAP_ACTION1= "http://localhost/getGramaNiladhariData";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://119.235.4.217/";` . Can the usage of 'localhost' in SOAP_ACTION be a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say i am not a Android developer so i coudn't provide you the exact answer but i can give you some hints what going wrong with my view point

Hopefully your Request is not that much cool to understand i guess by the server

**What i think is your request is seems like this**

```
REQUEST:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:getGramaNiladhariData/>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

***so its returns this***

```
stdClass Object
(
    [getGramaNiladhariDataResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gnName] => 
            [address] => 
            [workingDays] => 
            [gnDivision] => 
            [contactNumber] => 
        )

)
```

**So Your Request must be like this**

```
REQUEST:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:getGramaNiladhariData>
                <ns1:gndLifeCode>3-2-09-060</ns1:gndLifeCode>
            </ns1:getGramaNiladhariData>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and then you will get the exact answer

And also make sure your tags of xmlns such as ns1, SOAP-ENV (in my case) these are same,
to review that i recommend to use soap ui

Cool

Answer (score 0):

the Imports:

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
```

Web service:

```
/*web service parameters*/
private static final String TAG = SearchResultFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetMethod";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetMethod";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://127.0.0.1/App_Services/service.asmx";
```

This is how i use it...

```
private SoapObject CallWebServiceDemo() {
    SoapObject result = null;
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Here I think you are meaning that my code is too long .When I used the above format I got exceptions,meaning that I can't do network operations in mainUI(MainActivity).That is why , I had to use a supporting class extending  AsyncTask class,with 3 overriden methods.

Comment: Yes, you must use it within the AsyncTask class, i just showed you the configuration of this Request

Comment: I've used the same steps that is mentioned in the above format.But it doesn't work

Comment: I work with this, for 5 applications i think you should recheck what do you accept inside the Response, it might be a problem in WebService.

Comment: The parameter string I am passing to webservice is, "3-2-09-060".Can the '-' in input string  be the reason,for webservice not to return values.

Comment: It might not convert it into a valid XML, the cause '-'. So it could be, why can't you parse these in the webservice, just figure out the convention in there don't give the android app, work so hard, don't forget it's Mobile Application

Comment: I've edited my question.& it now contains the,request & response in xml.Can u please check it again?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to change output to xml format:

```java
httpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
String resultString = httpTransport.responseDump;
```