# Unmarshalling to generic type in soap webservice anytype in xml

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I am using soapwebservice. I have a generic class whose attribute in xsd is

```
<xs:element name="id" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0"/>
```

How can I pass value to this attribute through soap UI? I am using in xml `<id>amar</id>` which is not working properly. I am getting value null in java object populated by jaxb.

Where am I going wrong? I want it unmarshalled as a string type. Any help is appreciated. I searched and found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375998/soapobject-result-returns-anytype-as-value) in stackoverflow. but even it does not give a clear insight into how to use in xml.

Comment: This is a SoapUI question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using `<id xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">myID</id>`